# Slim Framework Pretty JSON

Tags: php, json, slim

How to configure Slim Framework to output pretty JSON?

In PHP native I could do it using this syntax

```
json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Slim docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html):

> Slim’s Response object has a custom method withJson($data, $status,
>   $encodingOptions) to help simplify the process of returning JSON data.
>
> The $data parameter contains the data structure you wish returned as
>   JSON. $status is optional, and can be used to return a custom HTTP
>   code. $encodingOptions is optional, and are the same encoding options
>   used for json_encode().

So, if you're using `withJson` to return JSON response you can use it like:

```
return $response->withJson($data, 200, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```